# Display a portion of a paged Wordpress page only on first page of paged set?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a wordpress page with 2 loops.

The first displays the 3 newest posts, styled one way.

The second is a paged loop that displays all but the first 3 posts, in descending order ("previous articles") in a more condensed list style.

It works, but of course the first loop displays again on all the pages; I'd rather have only the initial page show that first loop's "current" articles.

I tried wrapping first loop with "if paged == 1" but then the first section disappeared from all pages, even the first, so I must've done it wrong.

[Here's the page as it currently stands.](http://happeninginthehills.com/on-our-radar/)

Comment: can you share the code you are using ? i'll take a look and let you know ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the page number in different ways, 
first from the loop variables use this code `$page = get_query_var('paged');` to get the page number

second from the page url :

```
function get_url_var($name)
{
    $strURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $arrVals = split("/",$strURL);
    $found = 0;
    foreach ($arrVals as $index => $value) 
    {
        if($value == $name) $found = $index;
    }
    $place = $found + 1;
    return $arrVals[$place];
}

$page = get_url_var('page');
```

After getting the url just put the first group of post in a loop, check if its the first page or not

```
if ( $page == 1 )
{
 // first loop here,  
}
```